# PHP: Remove all Classes and IDs but one

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**What do I want to achieve?**

I want to remove all classes and IDs from list-elements. One special class should remain.

**My approach**

$menu is where the li-elements are stored. It is a string. I remove all classes and IDs using 
`$menu = preg_replace('#\s(id|class)="[^"]+"#', '', $menu);`
I'm pretty sure there is some kind of exception that I can inject somewhere here: `(id|class)="[^"]+"#'`

**The background**

I've written a responsive menu, and I want to insert it into a wordpress project as part of my training. I want to remove the classes and IDs, so no pre-set style will crush my menu design. Anyway, I need the .current-menu-item class generated by wordpress to know the active menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [nav_menu_css_class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) filter.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_remove_nav_classes');
function my_remove_nav_classes($classes, $item, $args, $depth) {
   return [];
}
```

If you place this in your functions.php or plugin file it should do the trick.